# Accessing data from an Adorner

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner

I'm writing a 2D graphics tool in C# and WPF, and I'm using `Adorners` on the `Shapes` drawn to `Canvas`.

I'd like the adorners to highlight when a shape is considered "selected", which I'm currently doing using `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events.

However, the user can select multiple shapes, so not all of the shapes will receive both of the mouse events.

I have a class that manages the drawing, which holds a `List` of the selected shapes. What is the best way to give the adorners access to this data, so they can see if their adorned element is selected?

Some thing's I've considered:

- Making the `List` global - bad idea
- Sub-classing each shape to add a "selected" property - would require changing all references to the shapes in my class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an attached dependencyproperty you set on your shape - then you can set that property when you select one. 
The adorner can have a visibility binding to the property on the shape so you get visibility set automatic.

You can also use the Tag property on the shape to store values - that is the old way of doing it :)

Comment: You can also implement PropertyChanged on the dependencyproperty to automatically set an adorner on the selected shapes.

Comment: I looked at Tags, but they're not available for Shapes, only for Adorners! Can I add the Tag feature to an existing class?

Comment: The shapes are Ellipse, Polygon and Rectangle deriving from System.Windows.Shapes.Shape right? The Shape class has the Tag property. It comes from FrameworkElement so you should have it :)